# Como criar um stored procedure do Postgresql a partir de um código Java

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, spring

Pesquisando na internet por uma solução para criar um banco de dados em um servidor Postgresql para meu projeto Spring, eu encontrei o seguinte tópico no StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389124/simulate-create-database-if-not-exists-for-postgresql

onde existe o seguinte Stored procedure para essa tarefa:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'mydb') THEN
   RAISE NOTICE 'Database already exists'; 
ELSE
   PERFORM dblink_exec('dbname=' || current_database() -- current db
                      , $$CREATE DATABASE mydb$$);
END IF;

END
$do$
```

Eu quero poder executar esse código a partir do meu código Java, sem precisar usar algum comando do banco de dados (eu já estou criando as tabelas do banco de dados via Hibernate, mas eu preciso criar um banco de dados antes através d pgAdmin3, etapa que quero evitar).

O ideal para mim seria chamar esse código através da seguinte classe Service:

```
@Service
public class InstallService {

    private String query = "";

    public boolean create_database(String maquina, String usuario, String senha) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean create_user(String usuario, String senha, String email) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu consegui o resultado desejado com o seguinte código:

```
@Service
public class InstallService {

    private String property_file = "database.properties";

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioHome usuario;

    @Autowired
    private AutorizacaoHome autorizacao;

    public boolean create_database(String maquina, String usuario, String senha) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException");
        }
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://"+maquina+"/postgres";
            System.out.println("url = "+url);
            System.out.println("usuario = "+usuario);
            System.out.println("senha = "+senha);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,senha);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE datname = 'horario'");
            rs.next();
            int counter  = rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("counter = "+counter);
            if(counter > 0) {
                System.out.println("calling_create_tables");
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
                conn.close();
                create_tables(maquina, usuario, senha);
                return true;
            }

            stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE horario WITH OWNER "+usuario);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE datname = 'horario'");
            rs.next();
            int result = rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("result = "+result);
            if(result > 0) {
                System.out.println("calling_create_tables");
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
                conn.close();
                create_tables(maquina, usuario, senha);
                return true;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("SQLException");
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void create_tables(String maquina, String usuario, String senha) {
        System.out.println("create_tables");
        create_properties(maquina, usuario, senha);

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileInputStream( this.property_file );
            props.load(fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        config.setProperties(props);

        config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.Atributo.class);
        config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.ConfigHorarioLivre.class);
        config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.Evento.class);
        config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.HorarioLivre.class);
        config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.Key.class);
        config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.Tipo.class);
        config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.Value.class);
        config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.Autorizacao.class);
        config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.Usuario.class);

        try {
            String url = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,senha);
            SchemaExport schema = new SchemaExport(config, conn);
            schema.create(true, true);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        insert_default_values();
    }

    public void insert_default_values() {
        System.out.println("insert_default_values");
        String [] autorizacoes = {"cad_evento", "lista_evento", "cad_horario", "lista_horario", "cad_usuario", "lista_usuario", "cad_campo", "cad_tipo", "cad_permissao"};
        for(int i=0; i<autorizacoes.length; i++) {
            autorizacao.persist(new Autorizacao(autorizacoes[i]));
        }
    }

    public void create_properties(String maquina, String usuario, String senha) {
        System.out.println("create_properties");
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("jdbc.Classname", "org.postgresql.Driver");
        props.setProperty("jdbc.url", "jdbc:postgresql://"+maquina+"/horario" );
        props.setProperty("jdbc.user", usuario );
        props.setProperty("jdbc.pass", senha );

        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream( this.property_file );
            props.store( fos, "propriedades" );
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean create_user(String login, String senha, String pnome, String unome) {
        System.out.println("create_user");
        Usuario novo = new Usuario(login, senha, pnome, unome);

        if(usuario.persist(novo))
            novo.setAutorizacao(autorizacao.findALL());
        else
            return false;

        if(usuario.merge(novo) != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que consultar as tabelas de sistemas do postgresql para saber se o banco já existe. Se não existir, você faz uma nova chamada.
Ex. (usando SQL);

```
String sqlIfExist = "SELECT count(*) = 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = :nomeDB";
Query q = session.createSQLQuery(sqlIfExist);
q.setString("nomeDB", "mydb"); // troque mydb pelo seu database
boolean existe = (Boolean) q.uniqueResult();
if (!existe) {
    String sqlCreateDB = "CREATE DATABASE :nomeDB";
    Query qc = session.createSQLQuery(sqlIfExist);
    qc.setString("nomeDB", "mydb"); // troque mydb pelo seu database
    qc.executeUpdate();
}
```

Lembrando que o seu usuário no PostgreSQL deve ter permissão para criar o banco.